# Sum all cells for which corresponding cell is not a formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Following [this 2019 question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55803385/1469208) and it's [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55804587/1469208) I have learnt that to sum all cells that has formula, I should use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((ISFORMULA(B5:M5)=TRUE)*B5:M5)
```

And to sum the cells that doesn't have formula, I should consider:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((ISFORMULA(B5:M5)=FALSE)*B5:M5)
```

But, can I use the above (or something else) in the way similar to using `SUMIF` with *three* arguments (summing values from other column than the one that is checked for conditions)?

Meaning that I need to solve following problem:

> Sum all values in the range `I2:I21`, but only for those cells for which the corresponding cells in the range `B2:B21` are not a formula / enumerable value.

I wonder if I'm not excepting too much and whether such a problem can be solved with just a formula, without using a macro.

Comment: Have you tried simply replacing the references in the formula you posted? `SUMPRODUCT(ISFORMULA(B2:B21)*I2:I21)`. Also, I don't see three arguments here.

Comment: @JosWoolley Thanks for trying to help me and sorry for asking too quickly / too early. I have managed to solve this problem and I am posting an answer right now. I think that it is pretty much close to your proposed solution. When using exactly your proposed formula, I am getting an incorrect results, but I am too Excel newbie to tell you why.

Answer (score 1):

The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55804591/1469208) posted under [mentioned question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55803385/1469208) has gave me an insight to solve this problem.

Using following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((I2:I21)*(NOT(ISFORMULA(B2:B21))))
```

gives me exactly the values that I want. That is: sum of all values in `I2:I21` range for which corresponding cell in `B2:B21` range is a "hardcoded" value and not a result of an evaluable formula.